# Error : names the constructor, not the type. while compiling with g++4.6.1

Tags: c++, g++, aix

I am compiling the code with g++4.6.1 on aix6.1 and getting this error:-

```
ViaChecks.h:14:3: error: 'BuPolygonEX<AllPass<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal3> > > >::IOPS::Base {aka BuPolygonCore<bu_polygon_clean_func, no_derivatives, AllPass<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal3> > > >::IOPS}::IOPS' names the constructor, not the type
```

The structure is defined as :

```
struct ViaSquareCheck : BuPolygonEX<AllPass<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal3> > > > {
  typedef BuPolygonEX<AllPass<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal3> > > > Base;
  DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT(Base::IOPS, void update() { Base::update(); i().xregion_1nm_oversize(x0nm); o().xregion_1nm_oversize(x0nm); o().derivatives(x_dom); o().bu_polygonized(yes); }); // via_square_dim property is added inside
  membert(int, amount, -1, ViaSquareCheck);
  ViaSquareCheck();
  ViaSquareCheck* output(DFC* dfc) { return set_output(0,dfc); } // single output returns good vias
  ViaSquareCheck* set_output(int k, DFC* dfc);
  void option(const string& pname, const string& pval); // some options change engine properties
private:
  BadViaMultiplexer<C>* mux;
  GIM2a<APC> bad_via_gim;
  GIM2a<APC> good_via_gim;
  member(bool, linked, false);
  member(bool, ok_45, false);
  void link();
  member(ViaSquareCheckNetProcess*, np,NULL);
};
```

Definition of DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT:-

```
#define DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT(SSSS, extras...) \
struct IOPS : SSSS { \
      EnginePropertiesVector& i() { return SSSS::i(); }; \
      EnginePropertiesVector& o() { return SSSS::o(); }; \
      EngineProperties& i(int n) { return SSSS::i(n); }; \
      EngineProperties& o(int n) { return SSSS::o(n); }; \
      typedef SSSS Base; \
      extras; } ep_;
```

Thanks.

Comment: ¤ i think, but given earlier encounters of some 800 and 900 line C functions i'm not sure, that this must be the ugliest code i've seen. ouch. anyway, writing `T::T` instead of `T` is one way to get this error. perhaps that happens within the evil macro. what i did was simply to *google the error message*. cheers & hth.,

Comment: What is `DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT( )` macro ? Paste its body.

Comment: @ Alf P. Steinbach : If you dont understand anything, asking or clarifying is the best way to kill the doubt. You could provide a better approach instead of voting to close. huh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagnostic is given if you use the name

```
myclass::myclass
```

This name does not denote the class `myclass` but its constructor(s)

Comment: It will give "was not declared in scope" error for the other variables which we are using.

Answer (score 1):

It is a qualified name like `Base::IOPS,` we need to have a `typename` before that. You need to pass a type instead of qualified name `Base::IOPS`, so i defined a type

```
typedef Base::IOPS MYIOP
```

and then passed that type, so the error "this is not a type" is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess your source code with something like

```
g++ -C -E yoursource.cc | grep -v '^#' > yoursource.ii
```

(the `grep -v` removes the line numbering)

then compile the preprocessed form with

```
g++ -Wall -c yoursource.ii
```

then look at the locations of the error message in `yoursource.ii`

You might also ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`.

But as others pointed out, your code is not very pretty...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that when you say:

```
DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT(Base::IOPS, ...
```

You should write:

```
DEFINE_ENGINE_PROPERTIES_INHERIT(Base, ...
```

That is, without the `::IOPS`.